# '<' character ingored by jQuery html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple web app which demonstrates a common [Reflected XSS attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65142/what-is-reflected-xss) scenario, and I need to inject untrusted user data coming back from the server into an html page.

I need to use something like jQuery `html()` method because, unlike the `text()` method, it doesn't turn the input into a simple string.

The problem is that what comes after '<' character is ignored by jQuery `html()` method.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```js
if($('input#search-keyword').val()){
    
    //Fetch the search keyword from the hidden input field
    var keyword = $('input#search-keyword').val();
  
    //Inject the keyword to the DOM.
    $('span#keyword-reflect').html(keyword);

    //ISSUE: 
    //if keyword == '/><script>...</script>' it only injects />'
}
```

Can I achieve that using any other method except `eval` or jQuery `html()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not ignored. `<script>` doesn’t *run* when it’s assigned to `innerHTML`, but it does become part of the DOM. If you want a script to run, the easiest way is an `<img>` that fails to load and an `onerror` handler:

```
<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>
```

Comment: You are correct. It's not ignored but it's just not run. Using the img tag with the onerror handler works perfectly. Thanks